# DBMS_WM Export with condition in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I have some versioned table in my Oracle database.
I need to export these tables from one database to other database but based on some condition.
I have used below code from [oracle-docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28396/long_ref.htm#i114714)
I need to export below Workspace based on the sql.

```
/*    LT table with join condition */         
    SELECT
        H1.workspace , count(*)
        FROM  WMSYS.ALL_VERSION_HVIEW H1,
              EMPLOYEE_LT M1,
              DEPT_LT t1 
        WHERE H1.version=M1.wm_version 
        and t1.empid=M1.empid 
        and t1.deptid in (select d_id
                            from DEPT_LOC
                           where Location = 'NORWAY'
                          );
```

[image]

Here is my export code

```
execute dbms_wm.Export('EMPLOYEE','EMPLOYEE_STG','WS-27917', export_scope=>DBMS_WM.EXPORT_MODIFIED_DATA_ONLY,AUTO_COMMIT=>TRUE);
execute dbms_wm.Export('EMPLOYEE','EMPLOYEE_STG','WS-38904', export_scope=>DBMS_WM.EXPORT_MODIFIED_DATA_ONLY,AUTO_COMMIT=>TRUE);
execute dbms_wm.Export('EMPLOYEE','EMPLOYEE_STG','WS-39376', export_scope=>DBMS_WM.EXPORT_MODIFIED_DATA_ONLY,AUTO_COMMIT=>TRUE);
```

Like above I have run the same query with all different workspace.
Output of this query is like I will have `EMPLOYEE_STG` will be created with the workspace I have passed in the query.

But in real time whole Employee table has been created as `EMPLOYEE_STG` table with all the records

```
/*    ONLY LT table */ 
SELECT
      H1.workspace , count(*)
      FROM  WMSYS.ALL_VERSION_HVIEW H1 , 
            EMPLOYEE_LT M1
      WHERE H1.version=M1.wm_version
group by  H1.workspace                       
    ;

/*    STG table after dbms_wm.export() */     
    SELECT WM$WORKSPACE, count(*) 
    FROM EMPLOYEE_STG 
    group by WM$WORKSPACE;
```

[image]

Now I needed only those workspace which are coming as a result of above sql not the full Employee table.
But my `dbms_wm.export` is creating whole table.

In [Oracle-docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28396/long_ref.htm#i114714) I have seen below part like `where` condition but I am not sure how to use that. How to use **subquery** in `dbms_wm.export()` .
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have successfully reached to create an export table with condition. The steps is not direct way.
Ref cursor and record type variable needed to achieve this.

```
set serveroutput on
    DECLARE
      TYPE r_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
      c_object r_cursor;
      TYPE rec_emp IS RECORD
      (
        v_ws  WMSYS.ALL_VERSION_HVIEW.WORKSPACE%type,
        v_empid    EMPLOYEE_LT.empid%type
      );
      v_rec rec_emp;
      v_exporttable VARCHAR2(100):='EMPLOYEE';
      v_location  VARCHAR2(100):='NORWAY';
      v_cursor_SQL VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
    v_cursor_SQL := '
                SELECT 
                DISTINCT H1.WORKSPACE, M1.empid
                FROM  WMSYS.ALL_VERSION_HVIEW H1,
                      '||v_exporttable||'_LT M1,
                      DEPT_LT t1 
                WHERE H1.version=M1.wm_version 
                and t1.empid=M1.empid 
                and t1.deptid in (select d_id from DEPT_LOC where Location = '||v_location||')';
    -- dbms_output.put_line(v_cursor_SQL);
      OPEN c_object FOR v_cursor_SQL;
      LOOP
          FETCH c_object INTO v_rec;
          exit when c_object%NOTFOUND;
          dbms_wm.Export(v_exporttable,v_exporttable||'_STG',v_rec.v_ws,where_clause=>'empid='||v_rec.v_empid,export_scope=>DBMS_WM.EXPORT_MODIFIED_DATA_ONLY,AUTO_COMMIT=>TRUE);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c_object;
    END;
    /
```